# Launch a stored html page in WebView or Browser - Objective C/Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have saved an html page using the following line of code :

```
NSURL *yoyoyo = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"www.google.com"];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:yoyoyo]; 
NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
NSString *documentsDirectory = @"/Users/xxxx/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/";
NSLog(@"%@", documentsDirectory);
NSString *htmlFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.html"];
[html writeToFile:htmlFilePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

The file named as gets saved as "file.html" folder in the path mentioned i.e. documentsDirectory. Is there a way that I can open this file in safari or webView of my application ?? Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to load it in your web view, do the following

```
NSString *htmlFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.html"];
NSString *htmlContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFilePath
                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                                      error:NULL];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlContents baseURL:nil];
```

You also have an issue in getting `documentDir`

Instead of

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = @"/Users/xxxx/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/";
```

use

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
```

Save the file again and try to load using the above code

Comment: what is the problem, check if htmlContents has any string in it

Comment: Write NSLog(htmlContents); after the loading of htmlContents and go to the console and check that it has any value

Comment: kz .. I did that .. nothing was obtained in the gdb. btw I think in your htmlContents line of code .. it should be stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFilePath rather than stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlContents

Comment: yes .. I tried executing the updated one too .. but I was getting nothing displayed in the gdb.

Comment: still .. I am unable to get anything in the gdb printed or displayed in my webView. :(

Comment: you will need to post more code, so that i can figure out whats wrong

Comment: I was using wrong url .. it should be as stated by coder110 below :) :)

Answer (score 1):

try the url in this format http://www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

It can be as simple as:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: htmlFilePath];
```

which would open your saved HTML file in Safari.

If your app has it's own webview, you can create a URLRequest and pass that along to your webview's "`loadRequest:`" method.

Comment: I am actually using a WebView, by using this m unable to display the html file in my WebView.

Comment: I have also tried using :  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:completelink];
    
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    
    
    webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    
    [webView loadRequest:request];

Comment: I suspect you have something "`nil`" or "`NULL`" somewhere along the way. Make sure your webView is not null (set a breakpoint in your Xcode debugger and look at the address of webView).  Also make sure "`request`" is not null (which it could be if your URL is somehow invalid).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code
This may be helpful for you.

```
NSString *htmlFile;

htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"abc" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:nil];


NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Where abc.html is your html file in application.